# Page title disappears after Ajax post back - ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

I'm working in a SharePoint application. I've a tree view control (Telerik) in my page where I load the children on demand. But after the partial postback the page title is getting disappeared (or showing some junk text which has couple of boxes(?)).

Any ideas?

Comment: If using Firebug, disable it, I have seen this before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution worked for me:

http://eschrader.com/2009/08/27/page-titles-disappear-after-ajax-event/

Comment: Perfect! Just the solution that fixes the problem easily.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem in IE with AJAX requests in general. As far as I remember there wasn't any fix for this bug. I had to rewrite the title (using JS) after every AJAX request.

Answer (score 0):

Viewsource the script generated .See if there is any conflict between the keyword title. If so you can contact telerik to fix this problem.